# how to add index suffix to each value in group

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure how to articulate this exactly, but say I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"], 'B': np.arange(5)})
df
   A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1
2  a  2
3  b  3
4  b  4
```

how would I add an index suffix for each groupby, to get:

```
df
   A    B
0  a_1  0
1  a_2  1
2  a_3  2
3  b_1  3
4  b_2  4
```

I can add a string to the end of values in colA with

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: "{}_{}".format(x, ...))
```

I'm just not sure how to index the groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
df.A + '-' + df.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1).astype('str')
Out[19]: 
0    a-1
1    a-2
2    a-3
3    b-1
4    b-2
dtype: object
```

Comment: for my whole dataframe, I had to change `df['A'].astype(str) + ...` and then it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within each group, do a cumulative count. I store this in a separate column for clarity; you can store it in a separate object as well (eg, in the code, for all `df['C']` substitute `ccount`). Then add one to change the zero-indexing that is default to your 1-based indexing. After that, join the strings to produce your desired format.

```
>>> df['C'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount() + 1
>>> df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str) + '_' + df['C'].astype(str)

>>> df
     A  B  C
0  a_1  0  1
1  a_2  1  2
2  a_3  2  3
3  b_1  3  1
4  b_2  4  2
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `'Series' object is not callable` when i try this on my real dataframe. Creating the cumulative count column works, but for some reason it doesn't join the strings